# Oracle ords 1.17.4 in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-ords

I use an Oracle RDBMS 12c where APEX 5.1.4 is installed on it.I also have a WebLogic 12c server.
Environment :

windows 10

oracle 12c database

apex 5.1.4

ords 1.17.4

welogic 12c

1) The user APEX_PUBLIC_USER is open and has a known password.

2) Both deployments apex.war and i.war are with: State=ActiveHealth=OK  Yet, when I try to get the APEX page as: http://:

I get the error:

Error 500--Internal Server Error
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Thanks

Comment: What's in the log file from wls ?

Comment: Double check that ords version. There was never a 1.17.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ords 17.4 needs a support with weblogic server 12c :

Weblogic 12 deployments require the following workaround to avoid a Java class conflict that causes a 500 response when invoking ORDS:

You can set these System Properties in a number of ways, but the way we recommend this is done is update the settings for the server instance where ORDS is deployed.

The recommanded solution is :

In the WebLogic Admin Console navigate to:

Environnment-- Servers -- server-name-where-ords-is-deployed -- Server Start

Then enter the following in the Arguments field, then Save and restart that Server:

```html
 -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory=com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory 
 
 
-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

NB: Don't forget the hyphen "-" for each parameters and i also recommend to restart the server in weblogic console rather than do it in command console of your operating system.